# PHP efficient page handler

Tags: php, handler

I'm making a website that has URLs for each country and city, and name of restaurant.

(www.domain.com/country/city/restaurant-name)

I know how to do the Apache rewrites for it,

The question is how to make it as efficient as possible wuth php.

right now what I do is first declare a two-dimensional array of countries
and cities:

```
$countries = array("United-Kingdom"=>array("Bristol","London"),
               "Italy"=>array("Rome","Milan","Napoli"));
```

than I check if the city exists:

```
if (isset ($countries[$page])
```

and then i do use the in_array function for the city,
the restaurant name is looked up in the database.

The array of countries and cities is quite huge, so I want to know
if there's a more efficient way of doing this.

I though of maybe making a php file for each country and try to include it,
and have in each php file the array of cities.
and maybe set up a cron job that will update the files.

I wondered is the most efficient way of doing this that will use
the least processing CPU usage and make the server serve the pages as fast possible.

Comment: Why don't you have countries and cities in the db, since you're using it anyway for restaurants?

Comment: No Special reason, I just thought that making a MySQL query is more resource exhausting than setting an array, and the countries and cities are pretty much constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A faster way than using in_array would be to stick with isset(). You can structure your array like this:

```
$countries = array("United-Kingdom"=>array("Bristol"=>true,"London"=>true);
```

Then....

```
if(isset($countries[$country][$city])){
    //...
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer.  You don't need to check twice, only once.

Comment: and the idea of having a separate php file for each country? is it any good? my thoughts are that even the declaration of the huge array is pretty resource exhausting and maybe I can check which country it is and than declare the array only for that country. your answer is gr8 nonetheless :)

Comment: Thank you. if you don't want to use a database, you could keep a directory for each country with a file inside for each city. Then you could just check for the existence of a file: if(file_exists($country.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$city)) ... and if you find the file, then you can just crawl the directory to grab the cities.

Comment: Thanx a lot, I think that It'll be pretty hard to maintain this directory structure though, How about just a php file for each country that inside has a declaration of the array of cities? either that or maybe finding an effective way of managing the directory structure you mentioned

Comment: I'm not sure how managing the files is more difficult that creating a country file with arrays inside. Think about the steps: 1. You get a country, and city. 2. You check if country files exists before 3. doing an include(). Then 4. isset()? Vs: 1. Get country / city. 2. file_exists('Italy/Rome')? Making a way to read the directory and touch / delete files would be pretty easy. I wouldn't be surprised if you could find a script out there that already does that.

Comment: Hmmm.. you mean I do not include the file at all? actually it sounds good, all I really need is to know if the city exists, but it sounds like there has to be a simpler way to manage this than creating these files, you'll probably say put this in a database, but the files thing sounds faster than a database.

Comment: That's right, you don't need to include the file, only check for its existence. Also, even if you only care about the existence of the city, checking for file_exists(country/city) will still simply return false if the country does not exist. And if the country does not exists, the city shouldn't either. Re: managing it, there's no getting around it. Creating/deleting files is about as easy as it gets. I can't imagine it's more difficult than opening a file and editing code to modify your array. You are correct though, if this the only thing you're looking up, it will be faster than using a DB.